# Gerrit event on Jenkins doesn't trigger automatically on git push

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I'm new to Jenkins/Gerrit. I'm trying to integrate gerrit with jenkins. I've a jenkins project setup to be triggered when there is a changeset created (push) in my git repository, which is hosted with a gerrit project. The master branch doesn't accept direct push. I use following command to push to the repository.

> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

Now, when I do a push, the jenkins project doesn't kick off automatically. I can manually trigger gerrit event with, "Query and Trigger Gerrit Patches".

Below is the Gerrit server and Trigger plugin version.

> Gerrit Server Version: 2.10.3.1
>
> Gerrit Trigger Plugin: 2.12.0

I pretty much followed the [Gerrit Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) plugin guideline. The jenkins project setup is in the screenshot (1-3).

And for gerrit Project access permission, the project inherits from All-Projects. Here is the screenshot (4).

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be solved now. The key was following.

```
Gerrit Project
 -Branches
  -Type: Path
  -Pattern: ""
```

I was using Type "Plain" and Pattern "master". That didn't work.